Getting prediction percentages of mediapipe model in python
I have a python code that detects the irises with face landmarker model of mediapipe. But i want to get the percentages of the irirses (for exampe eyeLookUpRight and etc.). I wrote in js but couldn't wrote in python.
This is my code:
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_drawing_styles = mp.solutions.drawing_styles
mp_face_mesh = mp.solutions.face_mesh


drawing_spec = mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(thickness=1, circle_radius=1)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
with mp_face_mesh.FaceMesh(
    max_num_faces=1,
    refine_landmarks=True,
    min_detection_confidence=0.5,
    min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as face_mesh:
  while cap.isOpened():
    success, image = cap.read()
    if not success:
      print("Ignoring empty camera frame.")
      # If loading a video, use 'break' instead of 'continue'.
      continue

    # To improve performance, optionally mark the image as not writeable to
    # pass by reference.
    image.flags.writeable = False
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    results = face_mesh.process(image)

    
    # Draw the face mesh annotations on the image.
    image.flags.writeable = True
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    if results.multi_face_landmarks:
      for face_landmarks in results.multi_face_landmarks:
        
        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
            image=image,
            landmark_list=face_landmarks,
            connections=mp_face_mesh.FACEMESH_IRISES,
            landmark_drawing_spec=None,
            connection_drawing_spec=mp_drawing_styles
            .get_default_face_mesh_iris_connections_style())
    # Flip the image horizontally for a selfie-view display.
    cv2.imshow('MediaPipe Face Mesh', cv2.flip(image, 1))
    if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == 27:
      break
cap.release()

I tried this code by chatgpt but didnt work.
...
# Function to calculate percentages
def calculate_percentages(image, landmarks):
    height, width, _ = image.shape
    percentages = []
    for landmark in landmarks:
        x_percent = landmark.x / width * 100
        y_percent = landmark.y / height * 100
        percentages.append((x_percent, y_percent))
    return percentages

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

with mp_face_mesh.FaceMesh(
    max_num_faces=1,
    refine_landmarks=True,
    min_detection_confidence=0.5,
    min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as face_mesh:

    while cap.isOpened():
        success, image = cap.read()
        if not success:
            print("Ignoring empty camera frame.")
            continue

        image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        results = face_mesh.process(image_rgb)

        if results.multi_face_landmarks:
            for face_landmarks in results.multi_face_landmarks:
                mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
                    image, face_landmarks, mp_face_mesh.FACEMESH_CONTOURS,
                    landmark_drawing_spec=None, connection_drawing_spec=mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(0,255,0), thickness=1, circle_radius=1),
                )
                # Calculate percentages and print
                percentages = calculate_percentages(image, face_landmarks.landmark)
                print(percentages)
...


I got so many percentages but when i change direction of my irises it didnt change.
